# Login with google plus with out opening external browser in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

My app was recently rejected, because I am using Google Plus Login integration with external browser. So read a few threads, and found a solution to create `UIApplication` class to handle external browser, and use default `UIWebView`. I have done everything, but I have a problem to open google login page in`UIWebView`. Here is my code.

**LoginWithGoogle.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define ApplicationOpenGoogleAuthNotification @"ApplicationOpenGoogleAuthNotification"
@interface LoginWithGoogle : UIApplication
@end
```

**LoginWithGoogle.m**

```
#import "LoginWithGoogle.h"
@implementation LoginWithGoogle
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url {

    if ([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"googlechrome-x-callback:"]) {
        return NO;

    } else if ([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"]) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ApplicationOpenGoogleAuthNotification object:url];
        return NO;
    }

    return [super openURL:url];
}
@end
```

And I added LoginWithGoogle as the principal Class in `info.plist`. 
I catch notification and Open `UIWebView` into another class.
Now I want to open Google Plus login view in my own UIWebView, like Google's auto-open into Safari or external browser in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate of UIWebView.
I tried following code:

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"com.XXX.XXX:/oauth2callback"]) {
        [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:@"com.google.chrome.ios" annotation:nil];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;

}
```

But what should be the URL in above code? If I am wrong, then kindly guide me how to open Login Page in a UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

1) create a subclass of UIApplication, which overrides openURL:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define ApplicationOpenGoogleAuthNotification @"ApplicationOpenGoogleAuthNotification"

@interface Application : UIApplication

@end
```

.m

```
#import "Application.h"

@implementation Application

- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url {

    if ([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"googlechrome-x-callback:"]) {

        return NO;

    } else if ([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"]) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ApplicationOpenGoogleAuthNotification object:url];
        return NO;

    }

    return [super openURL:url];
}

@end
```

- this will basically prevent anything to be opened from Chrome on iOS
- we catch the auth call and redirect it to our internal UIWebView

2) to info.plist, add the Principal class, and for it Application (or whatever you named the class)

3) catch the notification and open an internal webview

4) inside the webview

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"com.XXX.XXX:/oauth2callback"]) {
        [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:@"com.google.chrome.ios"n annotation:nil];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

- or simmilar code, that handles the response
- you might want to use @"com.apple.mobilesafari" as sourceApplication parameter