# oAuth2 retrieve profile email in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I followed [this tutorial](http://technogerms.com/login-with-google-using-oauth-2-0-for-ios-xcode-objective-c/) and was able to authenticate successfully and got the access token, now I am struggling to understand how can I get email associated with user profile before closing webview and join back my controller.

Any suggestions? I understand that Google has SDK for this, but I don't want to go that route if my requirement is possible with the tutorial I am using.

```
if (verifier) {
                NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"code=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&redirect_uri=%@&grant_type=authorization_code", verifier,client_id,secret,callbakc];
                NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"];
                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [request setHTTPBody:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
                receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

            } else {
                // ERROR!
            }

           //Should I need to call another HTTP to retrieve email (or) email already available part of any other response?
```

If I need to call another HTTP, what URL should be invoked?

Comment: Hi could u tell me how u made authenticated request to get people.get API method and fetch all details. I am also using same tutorial as u followed. thanks

Comment: @Imran: I didn't use this approach. I just did https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started (only problem is, this increase my package size to almost 50MB)

Comment: i tried this also but able to get contacts from address book. Could u please tell me how could i get friends email id from above link that u have suggested me in comment.

Comment: My requirement was not about friends list, so I don;t have any code, but if you follow the documentation properly it seems they have few examples.

Comment: Thanks for urs quick response. I am able to get names image but not email id. They have talked about contact api and they have not given sample in ios regarding usage of contact api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an authenticated request to the [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) API method with the `userId` set to `me`. The [person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource) has an `emails` array and the email with `type` set to `account` is their verified email.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! will try it. While exploring Stack Overflow for the answers I came across this question which says their app was rejected because they are opening authentication in UI webview which I think is exactly what the tutorial I am referring also doing, is this not correct approach to solve this? your opinion would be really helpful. Here is the link for the question which says their app was rejected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063341/login-with-google-plus-with-out-opening-external-browser-in-iphone?rq=1